# Is it neccessary to use Json::value object=Json::objectValue to init?

Tags: c++, json

To work with json using a library jsoncpp,is it neccessary to use Json::objectvalue?

```cpp
Json::Value jsn_req;
jsn_req["header"] = Json::objectValue;
jsn_req["header"]["sid"] = 0;
```

or:

```cpp
Json::Value jsn_req;
jsn_req["header"]["sid"] = 0;
```

What's the difference between this?

Comment: i know it is a simple question,so you can just give me a link/blog to read~.

Comment: Well, did you try it? What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

read the source code, may help. operator[] create null value if the key is not exist. Then a null value can add not exist key too.

diff:

1. the first just trans the value of "header" from null to object, the second doesn't do it.
2. the first find "header" twice, but the second only find it once.

Both of then could work, but the second must be quick, it's not necessary to trans it.

```cpp
Value& Value::operator[](const char* key) {
  return resolveReference(key, key + strlen(key));
}

Value& Value::resolveReference(char const* key, char const* end) {
  JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE(
      type() == nullValue || type() == objectValue,
      "in Json::Value::resolveReference(key, end): requires objectValue");
  if (type() == nullValue)
    *this = Value(objectValue);
  CZString actualKey(key, static_cast<unsigned>(end - key),
                     CZString::duplicateOnCopy);
  auto it = value_.map_->lower_bound(actualKey);
  if (it != value_.map_->end() && (*it).first == actualKey)
    return (*it).second;

  ObjectValues::value_type defaultValue(actualKey, nullSingleton());
  it = value_.map_->insert(it, defaultValue);
  Value& value = (*it).second;
  return value;
}
```

Comment: thank you~ read source code is a good way